# Caching a web page with Backbone.js

Tags: javascript-framework

Can backbone cache a web page (similar to appcache) using Local Storage? I know that backbone can cache collections but I'd like to store the entire page. I'd also like to be able to update content once online. I've looked at various posts but they refer to only caching collections, not the entire web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store any string using localstorage, though the maximum size can vary depending on the browser.

Something like this could work: localStorage.setItem('page_name', $('body').html());

Comment: Your answer put me on the right track. I was able to accomplish all my requirements using only local storage.